# Make one way SIP video call

Tags: sip, asterisk, video-chat

Using Asterisk, CSipSimple and MicroSIP I was able to make a video call, but to make it work both parties should click on "video" and video will be transferred in both directions.

I do not like this. I want to get some "Skype-like" video calls. It means: If I started my video, other party should see it anyway without having to start it's own video.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes,it is posible. You need rebuild client  part.

When it get start of call notification you need put require to switch to video mode.